# Forge - Direction of Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge

The Forge documentation mentions “If you need an end user to authorize your app to act on the user’s behalf, you’ll want to check out this tutorial.” This makes it sound as if our app will be doing something from OurApp → Forge, reaching into Fusion data, pulling it out. Our desired action would be the user acting on their own behalf, with authorized permission, sending files to their account on OurApp.

I've genericized it, but our specific situation is as follows: we want Fusion360 users to be able to install our plugin and then send models in STL format (model derivative v2 API) to our service for 3D Printing or sharing with others. This same behavior exists for Tinkercad and is very popular, but the requirements change for Fusion, now that it is not a web app like Tinkercad.

Answer (score 0):

Autodesk Forge uses [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2) as its authentication strategy, and as part of that, the platform allows you to choose between *two-legged* and *three-legged* authentication.

*Two-legged authentication* means that a trust is established between your own application (with credentials that are generated for you when you create a Forge app on https://forge.autodesk.com) and the Forge services. Your application can manage its own data but it does not have access to your users data in other Forge applications.

*Three-legged authentication* means that a trust is established among 3 entities: your application, Forge, and your user. With an access token generated using 3-legged authentication, your application can also access the user's content in other Forge applications, for example, in BIM360 or Fusion Teams.

With that, if you plan on having your users upload STL files from a locally running instance of Fusion 360, you can use the simple 2-legged authentication and have your Forge application own and manage the uploaded data and the translated derivatives. But if you wanted to upload or download STLs to/from something like Fusion Teams, you would need the 3-legged auth workflow.